Merging attributes from line layer and polygon layer in QGIS
I am using QGIS 3.32 and have a grid layer with hexagons (so polygons) and a line layer. I would like the hexagons, which are overlapping the line layer to "take on" the attributes of the line layer. How to implement this?


i think you can use the Join attributes toolbox from QGIS. first try with line and polygon shapefile (hex). If that fails, then you can try to create a very small buffer over the line shapefile and then follow above step again. In parameter you can pass Overlap/Touching.

Thank you! The buffer, then join attributes worked like a charm!
